# What does the numpy.linalg.norm function?

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

What is the function of [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) method?

[In this Kmeans Clustering sample](https://mubaris.com/2017/10/01/kmeans-clustering-in-python/) the [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) function is used to get the distance between new centroids and old centroids in the movement centroid step but I cannot understand what is the meaning by itself

Could somebody give me a few ideas in relation to this Kmeans clustering context?

What is the norm of a vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy.linalg.norm` is used to calculate the norm of a vector or a matrix.

---

This is the help document taken from [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html#numpy-linalg-norm):

```
numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord=None, axis=None, keepdims=False)[source]
```

[image]

---

This is the code snippet taken from [K-Means Clustering in Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html#numpy-linalg-norm):

```
# Euclidean Distance Caculator
def dist(a, b, ax=1):
    return np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=ax)
```

It take `order=None` as default, so just to calculate the `Frobenius norm` of `(a-b)`, this is ti calculate the distance between a and b( using the upper Formula).

---

Comment: @bgarcial Here is wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: The same link was used twice by mistake

Answer (score 5):

I am not a mathematician but here is my layman's explanation of “norm”:

A vector describes the location of a point in space relative to the origin. Here’s an example in 2D space for the point [3 2]:

[image: Point in 2D space]

The norm is the distance from the origin to the point. In the 2D case it’s easy to visualize the point as the diametrically opposed point of a right triangle and see that the norm is the same thing as the hypotenuse.

[image: Point in 2D space showing relationship between norm and hypotenuse]

However, In higher dimensions it’s no longer a shape we describe in average-person language, but the distance from the origin to the point is still called the norm. Here's an example in 3D space:

[image: Point in 3D space showing the norm]

I don’t know why the norm is used in K-means clustering. You stated that it was part of determing the distance between the old and new centroid in each step. Not sure why one would use the norm for this since you can get the distance between two points in any dimensionality* using an extension of the from used in 2D algebra:

[image: Formula for distance between 2 points in 2D space]

You just add a term for each addtional dimension, for example here is a 3D version:

[image: Formula for distance between 2 points in 3D space]

*where the dimensions are positive integers

Comment: perfect explanation, thanks

Comment: I have an error in the graph of the 3 dimensional vector. The point is (4,2,2) not (3,2,2).

Answer (score 1):

numpy.linalg.norm function is used to get the sum from a row or column of a matrix.Suppose ,

```
>>> c = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3],
...               [-1, 1, 4]])
>>> LA.norm(c, axis=0)
array([ 1.41421356,  2.23606798,  5.        ])
>>> LA.norm(c, axis=1)
array([ 3.74165739,  4.24264069])
>>> LA.norm(c, ord=1, axis=1)
array([6, 6])
```